# Rspec - Format output as Progress/Documentation/HTML

Tags: rspec

Using Rspec, I want to be able to both see the standard progress bar, *and* output to a file containing the generated spec sheet in documentation format, *and* also have an html file generated, without running the tests multiple times.

How do I assign multiple formats and file targets for those formats?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. You can add the following to your .rspec file (or wherever you want to throw in these options, really)

```
--format progress
--format documentation --color -o "documentation/file"
--format html -o "web/file"
```

You can add multiple formats, and it will do ALL of them. You can then set the target of those formats (so they aren't just interlaced in your standard output) with the "-o" command, followed by the name of the file to create.

Comment: maybe you know how get all ruby puts in console and in generated html file? When I write --format html -o "web/file", I get html without my logs, but I need  it