# How to generate HTML reports from minitest specs

Tags: ruby, minitest, formatter

Is there a reporter for [minitest](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/) to generate HTML from minitest spec-runs? Or do I miss a built-in feature or flag?

Rspec has [formatters to generate HTML documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068842/73673), but I cannot find this for minitest.

In the end, I am looking to generate API (rdoc) documentation accompanied by the tests that describe my models and architecture. Being able to somehow make links between the rdoc and minitest would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Minitest has no such built-in. KISS and all that.

But the [Minitest Reporters](https://github.com/minitest-reporters/minitest-reporters) library does offer several formatters, including HTML.

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!(Minitest::Reporters::HtmlReporter.new)
```